# Random number generator and if then statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, random, numbers

This code is supposed prompt for two player names and generate a random number between 1 and 6 for each player. It is then supposed to compare those two numbers and provide the output of which player has the higher number or display tie if there is a tie. Sometimes this works and sometimes it does the opposite other times it says both numbers match when they don't.

Anyone have any ideas for me?

```
var playerOne = " "
var playerTwo = " "
var rollWinner = " "
var p1number = 0;
var p2number = 0;
var end = " "

main()



function main() 
{

    do {
      getNames()
      rollDice()
      displayResults()
      endProgram()
    }
  while (end == "yes")


}


function getNames()
{
    playerOne = prompt("Please enter the name of Player One: ")
    playerTwo = prompt("Please enter the name of Player Two: ")

}

function rollDice()
{

    p1Number = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1)
    p2Number = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1)



    if (p1Number > p2Number) 
    {
        return playerOne
    }

    else if (p1Number < p2Number)
    {       
        return playerTwo
    }

    else 
    {   
        return "Sorry no winner, there was a tie"
    }   


}

function displayResults()
{
    window.alert(playerOne + " rolled a " + p1Number)
    window.alert(playerTwo + " rolled a " + p2Number)
    window.alert("The winner is! " + rollDice())

}



function endProgram()
  {
    end = prompt("Do you want to play again? Enter yes or no")
    if (end == "no")
     window.alert("Thank you for playing");

    else if (end == "yes")

    return end;
   }
```

Comment: Works fine for me..http://jsfiddle.net/xQg9b/
Close all the statement with `semicolon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.alert("The winner is! " + rollDice())
```

This line calls `rollDice` again for a 2nd time.  You display the results of the first call then you re-roll and display the return value of the 2nd call (which may be different).

```
// display p1Number and p2Number from first roll
window.alert(playerOne + " rolled a " + p1Number)
window.alert(playerTwo + " rolled a " + p2Number)

// recall rollDice
window.alert("The winner is! " + rollDice())
```

Comment: Outstanding this is what I was missing and explains why sometimes it looked like it worked and other times it didn't.
What I did to fix this was pull the if then out of rollDice create its own function called logic and ran that from the final line in displayResults

Thanks again I've been staring at this for over an hour trying to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

In `displayResults()`, you are showing the values of `p1Number` and `p2Number` before assigning values to them (since that happens within `rollDice()`).

So your program is working, but your diagnostic output is misleading you.